# There's and enumeration

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, there-is

> There is one cup, one plate, and one spoon in the drawer

or

> There are one cup, one plate, and one spoon in the drawer

Which one should i use?

There's sounds more natural, but I feel like I'm talking about multiple items, so I should use There're.

Comment: There are *four* lights.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod, so "there's" is the correct answer?

Comment: Please see the duplicate linked here. If you still have problems, please edit your question to ad information.

Comment: This question is **unrelated** to the existential *there* although it uses it. It may be a good idea to modify the question replacing the existential *there* suitably.

Comment: In fact, I strongly suspect the "related" question, too, was sort of hijacked this way. (Compare the title and the answers there.)